# Perl: Clearing values in nested hash

Tags: perl, hash, nested

If I have a hash reference defined as:

```
my %hash1=(
    "a" => 1,
    "b" => 2,
    "c" => {
               "d" => 4,
               "e" => 5
           }
    );

my $r_hash1 = \%hash1;
```

Would using:

```
$r_hash1->{c}=();
```

To clear the keys in %hash1{c} for reuse be clean?

If so, I was also wondering if I had:

```
my %hash1=(
    "a" => 1,
    "b" => 2
);

my %hash2=(
    "d" => 4,
    "e" => 5
);

my $r_hash1 = \%hash1;
my $r_hash2 = \%hash2;

$r_hash1->{"c"} = $r_hash2;
```

Whether using:

```
$r_hash1->{c}=();
```

Would free the memory used by %hash2 for reuse as surely it would have to be used in hash context:

```
%$r_hash1->{c}
```

But this would look at $r_hash1 in hash context, rather than the contents of $r_hash1->{c}.

Thanks.

Comment: in the second question, you are defining $r_hash1 twice, I think you meant to define `my $r_hash2 = \%hash2;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to empty out a nested hash (but still have the hash exist) then you need to dereference it first:

```
%{ $r_hash1->{c} } = ( );
```

Alternatively, you could just assign an empty hashref in its place:

```
$r_hash1->{c} = { };
```

In your second example, if you set `$r_hash1->{c} = $r_hash2`, and then clear it with `%{ $r_hash1->{c} } = ( )`, the stuff in `%hash2` *will* be cleared. This is because you are dereferencing `$r_hash1->{c}`, which is a copy of `$r_hash2`, which is a reference to `%hash2`.

Here's a simple program which demonstrates the outcome:

```
perl -MData::Dumper -E '%h1 = ( a => 1, b => 2 ); %h2 = ( d => 4, e => 5 ); $h1{c} = \%h2; say Dumper \%h1; %{ $h1{c} } = ( ); say Dumper \%h1; say Dumper \%h2'
$VAR1 = {
          'c' => {
                   'e' => 5,
                   'd' => 4
                 },
          'a' => 1,
          'b' => 2
        };

$VAR1 = {
          'c' => {},
          'a' => 1,
          'b' => 2
        };

$VAR1 = {};
```

This is slightly abbreviated (I didn't bother with the intermediate named references.) The first dump shows `%h1` with its reference to `%h2`. The second dump shows `%h1` after dereferencing the reference and clearing it out. The third dump shows the original `%h2` after it has been cleared.

On the other hand, if you use `$h1{c} = { }`, the original `%h2` will be unaffected, because you are simply replacing the value of `$h1{c}`. It was originally a reference to `%h2`; now it's a reference to a new anonymous hash.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure using {} would affect the priority; and sorry, missed out a line - corrected it.